# Use of logical and for an xquery delete in tsql

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, xquery

Is it possible to use a logical and operator with an xquery statement inside a stored procedure to delete an element only if its parent element has a specific value AND it has a specific value? Such as:

```
SET @profiles_xml = (SELECT profiles from tbl_applied_profiles WHERE profiles.value('(Profile/ID)[1]','int')= @profile_id)
    SET @profiles_xml.modify('
    delete
    if(/Profile/User/ID=sql:variable("@user_id")) and (/Profile/User/Activities/Activity/Name = sql:variable("@activity_name"))
    then (/Profile/User/Activities/Activity)
    else()
    ')
```

I would like to delete the Activity only if the User ID element and Activity Name element match the given parameters.
The xml in profiles_xml looks like this:

```
<Profile>
  <ID>20</ID>
  <User>
    <ID>BC4A18CA-AFB5-4268-BDA9-C990DAFE7783</ID>
    <Name>somename</Name>
    <Activities>
      <Activity>
         <Name>activity1</Name>
      </Activity>
    </Activities>
  </User>
</Profile>
```

But in the future there will potentially be multiple  elements in each  and Multiple  elements as children of the  element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
declare @XML xml = '
<Profile>
  <ID>20</ID>
  <User>
    <ID>BC4A18CA-AFB5-4268-BDA9-C990DAFE7783</ID>
    <Name>somename</Name>
    <Activities>
      <Activity>
         <Name>activity1</Name>
      </Activity>
    </Activities>
  </User>
</Profile>'

declare @user_id nvarchar(50) = '20'
declare @activity_name nvarchar(50) = 'activity1'

set @XML.modify('delete /Profile[ID = sql:variable("@user_id")]
                        /User/Activities/
                        Activity[Name = sql:variable("@activity_name")]') 

select @XML
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I have to use
`@user_id nvarchar(50)`
`@activity_name nvarchar(50)`
so it would be 
`SET @xml.modify('
 delete /Profile/User[ID = sql:variable("@user_id")]/Activities/Activity/Name[sql:variable("@activity_name")]
 ')'
right? But when I try that I get the error:
`XQuery [modify()]: Only single (optional) numeric/boolean or node* expressions allowed as predicates, found 'xs:string ?'`

Comment: Ah I found that i had `/Activities/Activity/Name[sql:variable("@activity_name"‌​)]` when I needed `/Activities/Activity/Name=[sql:variable("@activity_name"‌​)]` but now I am getting the error:
`XQuery [modify()]: An expression was expected`

Comment: ok, I see what  I had wrong, just syntax again, thank you for the correct answer